# How does the C++ compiler interpret the == operator?

Tags: c++

```
   std::string somestring;
    /*...*/
    if("STRING_LITERAL" == somestring)
    std::cout << "Strings are Equal" << std::endl;
```

In the sample code above, how does a C++ compiler interpret the `==`
operator? As the `==` operator overloaded by the string class?

Answer (score 7):

If you're using `std::string` then you should have `#include`d the `<string>` header. Assuming this is the case then the `operator==` selected should be the non-member template function from `<string>` with appropriate template parameters deduced. (ISO/IEC 14882:2003 21.3.7.2 [lib.string::operator==])

```
template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
bool operator==(const charT* lhs,
    const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& rhs);
```

The `std::string` class (strictly class template specialization) doesn't contain any member overloads for `operator==`.

Comment: so the compiler tread it as a built-in operator or as a cast from std::string to (char *) followed by a comparison?

Comment: @ratzip: No. It's a overloaded function template. There's no conversion from `std::string` to `char*` involved. The implementation of the function template is specified to convert the left hand operand from `const char*` _to_ a `std::string` and call the `compare` member function on this converted operand, passing the right hand operand as parameter.

Comment: is that different from calling `c_str` on the RHS and `strcmp`? [Edit: d'oh, of course it is different, the RHS might have embedded nuls. Ignore me.]

Comment: Is the implementation required to be that bad? I.e. do you have to copy the whole `char[]` to a `std::string` even when you're just going to be reading chars from it? Usually it's specified "as if"

Comment: @MSalters: The "as if" rule always applies but the semantics must be identical to the result that you'd get _if_ you constructed a `std::string` from the _lhs_ and called `compare` passing the _rhs_.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The `operator==` is implemented as a free standing function, that's why the positioning is irrelevant. It could be

```
bool operator==(const string& str1, const char* str2){
  // ...
}
```

or

```
bool operator==(const char* str1, const string& str2){
  // ...
}
```

or even a simple

```
bool operator==(const string& str1, const string& str2){
  // ...
}
```

With an automatic conversion from `char const*` to `string`, as the relevant constructor of `std::string` is non-explicit.

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload of `operator==` that does the right thing:

```
template <class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
bool operator==(const charT* lhs,
                const basic_string<charT, traits, Allocator>& rhs);
```

You can find it in 21.3 §1 of the C++0x FDIS on page 635.

Comment: so we can say == operator overloaded by the string class?

Comment: @ratzip: You can overload operators as free functions, and that is what's happening here. You cannot provide this specific overload as a member function, because the first parameter is not of class type.

Comment: then how the complier treat the == operator in this case?As an overloaded == operator in global space?

Comment: @ratzip: It is an overload of `operator==` in the `std` namespace which is found through argument dependent lookup.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/operators/ , these overloads are defined:

```
bool operator== ( const string& lhs, const string& rhs );
bool operator== ( const char* lhs, const string& rhs );
bool operator== ( const string& lhs, const char* rhs );
```

Note that these are global functions, not methods of the `string` class (but they'll be implemented using [`string::compare()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/).